# Inserting VAL in :nth-child( X ) won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Why can't I use SlideNumber in the bottom...??
I tried to change `var SlideNumber = 3;` to `SlideNumber = 3;` but honestly, I'm fumbling in the dark.

```
if(window.location.hash != '') {
    var SlideNumber = 3;
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'blindY', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        speed:  700,
        cleartype:  1,
        startingSlide: $(window.location.hash).index(),
        timeout: 3000,
          after: function(curr,next,opts) {             
            $("#menu ul li:nth-child(SlideNumber)").addClass("active");
            ready = true;
          } 

    });
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add, you can avoid concatenation and crank up the performance a bit by using the [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) filtering method (which takes a zero-based index):

```
$("#menu ul li").eq(slideNumber-1).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate your `SlideNumber` variable into your selector, you need to break up your string and sandwich your variable between `+` operators:

```
$("#menu ul li:nth-child(" + SlideNumber + ")").addClass("active");
```

Otherwise your pseudo-class selector will simply appear as the string `":nth-child(SlideNumber)"` which isn't quite what you intend.